# Mysql multiple comparasion within one table

Tags: mysql

Mysql knowledge is far from perfect. I cannot get it all togheter so I thought I might give it a try here to understand the logic.

I've got two tables

Table: **office**

| ID (int (pk)) | name (varchar) |
| --- | --- |

and

Table: **staff**

| ID (int (pk)) | office_id (int not null) | chief_id (int) | name (varchar) | wage (float) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to :

a) Select all people, who get paid more than their direct chiefs

b) Select a list of all offices along with a person with the highest wage in each. if more than one person has the highest wage, display them all. The office should be selected even if it has no people.

c) Select all chiefs, who have exactly one direct subordinate.

d) Select all offices sorted by total wage of people in it, descending.

Any idea where I should start ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Start from a)

```
SELECT s.*, chief.wage AS chief_wage
  FROM staff s, staff chief
 WHERE s.chief_id = chief.id
   AND s.wage > chief.wage
```

Here we use self join to add the chief's data to all the staff. And then just compare salaries.